# How to solve an a+b equation?

Tags: python-3.x, math

New to python, what am i doing wrong here that it wont print my total out?

```
second = 2
third = 3
extra = input("what is the extra value?")
total = ("first+second+thrid+extra")
print("total,")
```

Comment: `"first+second"` is a string, while `first+second` is an expression

Comment: amendment               - first = 1
second = 2
third = 3
extra = input("what is the extra value?")
total = ("first+second+thrid+extra")
print("total,")

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour),
read up on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). there is a lot in your code not working  as you expect it to... please consider following a python tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

You are printing a string by putting in double quotes
Whereas expression should be like this:

```
result = first + second + extra
print(result) # without quotes
```

Comment: @Hayden If this answer solved your problem, consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/362830) by clicking the check mark. That way, this question is marked as solved. It also gives you and the answerer some reputation!